# iframe resize window.parent.postMessage from external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a iframe, that has this JavaScript implemented on the parent site:

```
// Iframe resize
var partner_url = '';
function check_resize() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        check_resize();
    }, 100);
    var height = getIframeContentHeight();
    parent.postMessage(height, '*');
}
```

https://koop.energie.check24.de/assets/ext/nrg/js/partner/iframe_extra.js

My iframe:

```
<div id="load-iframe"><p>Loading iframe ...</p></div>
<iframe id="iframe_id" src="https://koop.energie.check24.de/184979/stromsuchen/strom/el/?zipcode=10115&totalconsumption=2000" width="100%" height="400" onload="document.getElementById('load-iframe').style.display='none';"></iframe>
```

How can I get the hight of the iframe from the Script: `parent.postMessage(height, '*');` , so that the iframe resize the high automatically on my page?

I have no access to parent site, so I can not change anything on the parent site.

Answer (score 0):

I am fighting with this iframe resizer - https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer - you need to have a javascript file on the page you are trying to put into the iframe. Even with that it is really hard to do.